# "WebKitFormBoundary" when parsing POST using nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, post

I've implemented a http server parsing POST with the help from http://blog.thekfactor.info/posts/an-introduction-to-node-js-and-handling-post-requests/
(simply I don't want use express.)

However, what I got has

> [2013-10-10 10:27:29.670] [INFO] console - ------WebKitFormBoundaryMjfXHTTJYUdOInJ4
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="route"
>
> connector.sgtrackHandler.log
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryMjfXHTTJYUdOInJ4
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"
>
> {"appid":"1234","event":"test","params":{}}
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryMjfXHTTJYUdOInJ4--
>
> [2013-10-10 10:27:29.671] [INFO] console - { '------ WebKitFormBoundaryMjfXHTTJYUdOInJ4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"route"\r\n\r\nconnector.sgtrackHandler.log\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMjfXHTTJYUdOInJ4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="body"\r\n\r\n{"appid":"1234","event":"test","params":{}}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMjfXHTTJYUdOInJ4--\r\n' }

I cannot handle the such multipart form **WebKitFormBoundaryMjfXHTTJYUdOInJ4**...any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The code you're referring to parses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, whereas what's being posted is `multipart/form-data`, as defined in [RFC2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388).

To make it easier on yourself, you can use [`formidable`](https://npmjs.org/package/formidable) (which Express also uses).

Comment: If you are going to use formidable, there is a module named: express-formidable which can be used easily: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable

Comment: Getting *formidable* into one's node_modules is a challenge in itself. Have to use **npm install -d formidable@latest**. Then there's the poor documentation on this module. In plain language, it doesn't give readers a clue as to how to extract the form data from the XHR body.

Comment: @Trunk I find [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#example) quite easy to understand, and just plain `npm install formidable` works just fine for me.

Comment: Damned if I do. That example doesn't show how to parse anything - a case of asking people to just do what he does himself. Installing by the authors' own instructions got nowhere. I think formidable is a DEAD project now anyway.

Comment: @Trunk that example I linked to works as-is for me (although it doesn't use XHR, but I see absolutely no reason why it wouldn't also work with XHR requests).

Comment: @robertklep I ran the example you cite but ran into a CORS objection - *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.* That example seems to be returning the very data that it has been sent. I'd prefer to parse it on the server side and write each data ite, e.g. user, email, password, etc to the console. It appears that the FormData object is within the JavaScript engine of browsers Chrome & Firefox but NOT within the Node core packages.  I'm not sure which module is needed to import it either.

Comment: @Trunk a CORS rejection falls beyond the scope of `formidable`, it has to do with server configuration. The example _does_ return the data it has been sent, because it's just an example to show how to parse the form data. In a production environment, you'd use the parsed data for your specific purpose. The `FormData` object is a client-side object that generates `multipart/form-data` data that is subsequently parsed by `formidable` on the server.

Comment: All right - but using a data object like FormData and not having this object installable into the Node app via an npm module is like coding a message but not providing a codebook to the message receivers.

Comment: @Trunk `FormData` doesn't contain a parser, which is what you're looking for, isn't it? You can install [`form-data`](https://github.com/octet-stream/form-data) on Node.js, but its purpose is to generate `multipart/form-data` content, it's also not a parser (as opposed to `formidable`).

Comment: @robertklep  Well, if a new FormData object could be instantiated on the Node server side, you could then assign one of these to the body of the XHR containing one and then apply the FormData get methods to pick out the data items. I'll look again at this formidable thing and see if I can get it going on the local machine.